# VPC error: Unresolved resource dependencies [VPC] in the Resources block of the template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc, subnet

I am creating a vpc using cloudformation but it shows an error when I run it .I have created the vpc with internet gateway and 2 subnets one is public and another one is private but when I upload the yaml file to cloudformation it shows the following error
My yml file:

```
---
Description: An AWS VPC with two subnets.
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  myVPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 11.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      InstanceTenancy: default
  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
  VPCGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
  SubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      CidrBlock: 11.0.1.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
  SubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      CidrBlock: 11.0.0.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
  RouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
  InternetRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
  SubnetARouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetA
  SubnetBRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetB
  SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: "Internet Group"
      GroupDescription: "SSH traffic in, all traffic out."
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: "22"
          ToPort: "22"
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: -1
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
  InstanceSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Allow http to client host
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

  RDSSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Allow http to client host
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC

  RDSSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: !Ref RDSSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: 3306
      ToPort: 3306
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup

  myDBSubnetGroup:
    Type: "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup"
    Properties:
      DBSubnetGroupDescription: "description"
      SubnetIds:
        - !Ref SubnetB

  wahajwebserver:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-0bdcc6c05dec346bf
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: wahaj(webserver)
      SubnetId:
        Ref: SubnetA
      SecurityGroupIds: [!Ref InstanceSecurityGroup]

  wahajdbRDS:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      AllocatedStorage: 20
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2c
      DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
      DBInstanceIdentifier: wahajwebserver
      DBName: wahajdb
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref myDBSubnetGroup
      DeleteAutomatedBackups: true
      Engine: MySQL
      MasterUsername: wahajdb
      MasterUserPassword: wahajdb
      VPCSecurityGroups: [!Ref RDSSecurityGroup]
```

I have tried using validate function in the cli but the error is same unable to figure out the mistake.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your references to `!Ref VPC` should be `!Ref myVPC`. The `!Ref VPC` expects either a parameter or resource named `VPC` to exist, you've given your VPC resource the name `myVPC`.

```
---
Description: An AWS VPC with two subnets.
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  myVPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 11.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      InstanceTenancy: default
  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
  VPCGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
  SubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      CidrBlock: 11.0.1.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
  SubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      CidrBlock: 11.0.0.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
  RouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
  InternetRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
  SubnetARouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetA
  SubnetBRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetB
  SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: "Internet Group"
      GroupDescription: "SSH traffic in, all traffic out."
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: "22"
          ToPort: "22"
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: -1
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Hi, I have made the changes and edited my code. i am trying to launch and ec2 instance in public subnet (subnetA) and rds in private subnet (subnetB). it creates the vpc but roll back while creating the rds and ec2 instance. I have use a template and adjusted it according to my needs but  the yaml files fails. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the error while stack is build following error occurs and it rollbacks the stack

Comment: Add another subnet to the subnet group resource, it’s required for RDS. The DB will be created in one of the subnets :)